# How to parse and test response as key/value from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, postman

I've got the following json response:

```
{
"vin": "BAUV114MZ18091106",
"users": [
    {
        "role": "PRIMARY_USER",
        "status": "ACTIVE",
        "securityLevel": "HG_2_B",
        "firstName": "Etienne",
        "lastName": "Rumm",
        "nickName": "BastieW",
        "isInVehicle": false
    },
    {
        "role": "SECONDARY_USER",
        "status": "ACTIVE",
        "securityLevel": "HG_2_B",
        "firstName": "Test",
        "lastName": "DEde",
        "isInVehicle": false
    }
]
}
```

I want to test the "isInVehicle" key and pass the test, if it's true and fail the test, if it's false.

I was trying to do so with following test code, but it didn't work, tests are always passed, no matter what response I got.

```
pm.test("User is in Vehicle", () => {
_.each(pm.response.json(), (arrItem) => {
    if (arrItem.isInVehicle === 'true') {
        throw new Error(`Array contains ${arrItem.isInVehicle}`)
    }
})
});
```

Are there any ideas on how to solve my problem?

Comment: If `pm.response.json()` is the given json in your example, then you are not iterating over the users array. Do the following in your each-statement `_.each(pm.response.json().users => ...)` or ES5 `pm.response.json().users.forEach(user => {...})`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are iterating through an `object`(root object of your response) instead of the `user array`. The revised version would be:

```
var users = pm.response.users;
_.each(users, (arrItem) => {
    if (arrItem.isInVehicle) {
        //Do something  if isInVehicle is true 
    }
})
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do these using array properties,

`some` - returns true if at least one match the condition

`every` - returns true if all items match the condition

```js
const response = {
  "vin": "BAUV114MZ18091106",
  "users": [{
      "role": "PRIMARY_USER",
      "status": "ACTIVE",
      "securityLevel": "HG_2_B",
      "firstName": "Etienne",
      "lastName": "Rumm",
      "nickName": "BastieW",
      "isInVehicle": false
    },
    {
      "role": "SECONDARY_USER",
      "status": "ACTIVE",
      "securityLevel": "HG_2_B",
      "firstName": "Test",
      "lastName": "DEde",
      "isInVehicle": false
    }
  ]
};


pm.test("User is in Vehicle", () => {
  // I'm assuming you are looking for atleast one match
  const atleastOneMatch = response.users.some(user => user.isInVehicle);
  // if you are looking for all should match, uncomment the following code
  // const allShouldMatch = response.users.every(user => user.isInVehicle);
  
  if(atleastOneMatch) {
    // do your stuffs here
  }
})
```